# Change font for all a-z,A-Z letters in multiple language text Swift 4.2

Tags: swift

I have string with multiple language and what I try to do is change font for all ".*[^A-Za-z].*" in the string.

I try to work with regex.matches to get all matches range but the range I received is wrong.

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z].*", options: NSRegularExpression.Options())
    let value =  regex.matches(in: self.titleLabel.text!, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range:NSMakeRange(0, self.titleLabel.text!.count))
```

Comment: `NSMakeRange(0, self.titleLabel.text!.count)` => `NSMakeRange(0, self.titleLabel.text!.utf16.count)`? Also, are you sure about your regex pattern?

Comment: can't understand how that can help me, can explain ?

Comment: You might not be searching in the whole text, since by default string.count might return  a different value, so a different range. Also does your regex work on a online regex tool? Can it find the correct ranges?

Comment: ok I found the correct regex "[A-Za-z]+" , thanks this is work.

Answer (score 0):

`NSRange` and `NSRegularExpression` classes predate Swift and are based on the `NSString` concept that a *character* is equal to a UTF-16 code. On the other hand, Swift's `String` class has the concept that a character is a Unicode extended graphe cluster, i.e. the smallest unit you can select in a text editor. As a result, when you specify positions or length, `NSRange` / `NSString` and `String` differ.

The usual tricky is to use an `NSString` instance (instead of a `String` instance) for regular expression processing:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z].*", options: NSRegularExpression.Options())
let text = self.titleLabel.text! as NSString
let value =  regex.matches(in: text, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
```